# Java to JavaScript communication

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I want to access HTML elements from within my Java applet. Like I want to do following:

1. Pass a value of text box to applet
2. From applet I want to set some text inside an HTML page. Like applet takes some input from text box. Does processing and then print output as `href` on HTML page.

How can i do this?

I heard of some  java library: http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html.

But where can i download it from?

Answer (score 0):

I think those links take you to the current documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/LiveConnect_Overview

According to those documents, since Java 1.4 the classes to communicate with Javascript are inlude in the JRE, in `lib/plugin.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rhinohide](http://zelea.com/project/textbender/o/rhinohide/description.xht). Here's a demo that does exactly what you want [Events_2_Demo](http://zelea.com/var/cache/rhinohide-demo/textbender/a/b/rhinohideDemo/Events_2_Demo.xht).